# xcode ios connecting actions to button on action scene

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiactionsheet

I am a beginner at iOS dev.  I am trying to write a simple app that has two possible results associated with one button, depending on the variable of a particular field.

When a user presses the Walk button on my app and the state (variable) is Jumping, an action scene comes up.

If the state is Jumping and user presses Walk, an following scene pops up based on the following snippet:

```
- (IBAction)walk:(id)sender {
if ([_personState.text  isEqual:  @"Jumping"])
{
    UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Invalid Action - Force?"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Force", nil];
    [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
}
else {_personState.text =  @“Walking";}
```

}

When I click on Force, the personState is not updated to Walking.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if ([_personState.text isEqual: @"Jumping"] && buttonIndex == 0)
{
    _personState.text =  @"Walking";
}
```

Is my if statement incorrect?  Or have I made another error?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `isEqual:` but I think you want to be using `isEqualToString:` instead.

isEqual compares pointers while isEqualToString compares the value of the string.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not it - the state remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to debug, it'll make your life easier.

Place a break point in actionSheet: clickedButtonAtIndex:

in debug area at the bottom of Xcode type

```
po _personState.text
```

then type

```
p buttonIndex
```

po = print object

p = print primitive

You don't even need to type just hover your mouse over the variables and it'll show you the values